# cannot open include file 'Graphics.hpp' no such file or directory ,additional include for visual studio not working

Tags: c++, sfml

i m trying to use sfml in my project using visual studio 2019. Following sfml documentation to perform setup for visual studio i have performed all the action required

i have included `include` folder in `c/c++/additional include  directory` and also provided path for lib folder in linker setting and also provided additional dependencies in `linker/input` 
 but

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "i cant tolerate" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

this code shows  above mentioned error ,

```
cannot open include file 'Graphics.hpp' no such file or directory
```

it seems like include path is not working
how can i solve this issue
i tried many times but got same result

Comment: Your code sample says <Graphics.hpp> but the title says Graphics.h ? (Also a quick google search seems to indicate it should be <SFML/Graphics.hpp>)

Comment: sorry its .hpp i have updated my question

Comment: as the comment above says: did you try to `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` (note the additional path)?

Comment: @YePhIcK yes i tried but same error occurs

Comment: Then show what your include path is set to and the directory where you unpacked the sfml distribution to.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone facing the same problem please check the platform in the `project/properties` win32 worked for my particular problem